# change boot text on ubuntu minimal

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, ubuntu-minimal

On Ubuntu 18.04.3 minimal terminal how do I change the boot up text at the login and after login.
I want to change this:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS [hostname] tty1
```

and this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux)
* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The text for the `agetty` login is located in `/etc/issue`. Change the text to your needs and then restart all getty services with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart getty.target
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line may come from /etc/issue and may also be edited there, but in Ubuntu the traditional message of the day mechanism has changed and is replace by some more complex and dynamic system. Look first at the manpage:

```
$ man update-motd
```

and then have a look under /etc/update-motd.d/, all scripts in this directory are executed to build the file /run/motd.dynamic which will be displayed at login